# Is there an other way than using position: absolute, then position: ..., to make work a slider

Tags: javascript, css

Hello :) I wonder: Each time I want to use a slider, I have to define a parent element in position: relative, and his child in position: absolute, then using javaScript playing with the left position to make it move.

**For exemple:**

```
thisElement.style.left = 100 + "px";
```

I just feel uncomfortable using position: absolute at each time I want to do that.

**Is there a better way, without using position:absolute to make a slider work?**

Comment: what you mean by slider? is it something like `<input type="range">` or `overflow:scroll`?

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to use `position: absolute`.

```css
.bar {
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.slider {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(50px)
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
<div class="slider">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It wasn't my point. I didn't just want to put an element upon an other, I wanted to say, when I have to make move a child element inside a parent element, using the requestAnimationFrame() function in javaScript. I don't find other way that to define positions (relative, absolute), and I wanted to no if there is other way to be able doing that (that a child element can move relatively to a parent element). 

Sorry not being clear enough, thank you ^^

Comment: use `thisElement.style.transform = "translateX(" + value.toString() + "px)";`

Comment: Thank you ! I think that is gonna be useful.